# Populating Dropdown based on Geoserver service

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, javascript, web-service

I am new to web programming here. I have a table which has multiple columns including: Restaurant Name,Restaurant Id, Lat, Lon, City, District, Country.

My requirement is to build a web client using OpenLayers and JavaScript and allow users to search a Restaurant. I am using GeoServer to create a layer from this table.

My problem is : I have to add dropdowns i.e. one for country, another for District /City based on the country selected. This city/district/country mapping has to come from the table which is in Teradata. Is there any way I can get the data to populate the dropdown from GeoServer services Or do I need to create a new service of my own.
If I create my own service, can it be hosted from GeoServer.

Any inputs?

Comment: have you though about WFS?

Comment: I will check some examples to see if wfs with filter works. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple solutions, each differing in complexity and performance:

1. Use just OpenLayers and WFS to load the data in an array and then parse and display it yourself.
2. Use GeoExtJS and a WFS store. [Here](https://api.geo.admin.ch/main/wsgi/lib/geoext/examples/geocoder-wfs.html) is an example.
3. Create your own php (or any other server side technology) services, which return just the distinct values. Call these services in your JavaScript Application, to load the values.

Personally, I feel that if you have quite a bit of data, then Option 3 is the best. But the first two options are not bad, and might be appropriate in some cases.